# How to send a async http post in a service when app closes

Tags: android

I am trying to send an HTTP request using okhttp3 after detecting that the application has been force quit by the user. I currently have some code that successfully detects if the Android app has been force close. However, the async call will not work. I have also tried using a handler as well, but with no luck.

```
public class FKDService extends Service {

    public static void setData(String param1, String param2, Boolean check) {
        P1 = param1;
        P2 = param2;
        Check = check;
    }

    public static String P1;
    public static String P2;
    public static Boolean Check;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("FKD", "Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("FKD", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("url").newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("param1", P1)
                .addQueryParameter("param2", P2)
                .build();

        Log.d("FKD", url.toString());

        final Request req = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();


        client.newCall(req).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d("FKD", "FAIL");
                stopSelf();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d("FKD", "SUCCESS");
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to START_STICKY service as it will recreate by OS when it got killed. And On again creation you can check if there is any activity for your application is currently started or not if not then you can make the HTTP call.

Comment: @Avi how would you recommend going about checking if an activity is present?

Comment: You can listen to activity life cycle using Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks for more details please refer here(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you service destroy when you close app, you can send request in onDestroy service

Comment: that will not work as soon as your service is killed due to app process is destroyed. You can't start a thread from a destroyed process.

Answer (score 0):

try to use broadcast receiver for syncing process when network is enable its call service of sync in your required time interval

Comment: Could you give me an example of this? Thank you